# RxSwift: Single<T>, Single<T?> or Maybe<T>?

Tags: swift, traits, rx-swift, reactivex

I'm aware that this is a bit of a taste thing, but:

REST API requests to e.g. `GET /entity/{id}` can yield either one entity or a 404. In such cases, what would be the best [RxSwift trait](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/Traits.md#maybe) to use?

- A `Single<T>` that emits an `error`-event if the entity is not found
- A `Single<T?>` that emits an `.next(nil)`-event if the entity is not found
- A `Maybe<T>` that emits no elements and just completes if the entity is not found

What would be best practice?

Answer (score 2):

API Design is always a matter of personal preference, but IMHO I would use a regular `Single<T>`.

If you ever find yourself using a `Single<T?>`, you probably meant to use a `Maybe` :)

I would either do

`Single<T>` - And handle errors either with `materialize()` or by regular catching

*or*

`Single<Result<T>>` - Using an intermediate result type so errors don't terminate the sequence.